# What's distutils' equivalent of setuptools' `find_packages`? (python)

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have a `setup.py` file that checks if the user has `setuptools` and if he doesn't, then I am forced to use `distutils`. The thing is that, to make sure the submodules are installed, I use `setuptools`' find package:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
packages = find_packages()
```

and then proceed from there.

However, I'm not sure how to do that with `distutils`. Is there an equivalent function or do I have to manually look for subdirs that have an `__init__.py` inside of them? If that is the case, is it acceptable for me to require `setuptools` to install my package and just forget about `distutils`?

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is perfectly acceptable to use setuptools; the vast majority of packages on PyPI already do.

If you want to re-invent the `find_packages()` wheel, then yes, look for directories with `__init__.py` files in them. This is what the [`setuptools.PackageFinder` class](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/04d10ff025e1cbef7ec93a2008c930e856045c8a/setuptools/__init__.py#L34) does. A simplified re-implementation would be:

```
import os
from distutils.util import convert_path


def find_packages(base_path):
    base_path = convert_path(base_path)
    found = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path, followlinks=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d[0] != '.' and d not in ('ez_setup', '__pycache__')]
        relpath = os.path.relpath(root, base_path)
        parent = relpath.replace(os.sep, '.').lstrip('.')
        if relpath != '.' and parent not in found:
            # foo.bar package but no foo package, skip
            continue
        for dir in dirs:
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, dir, '__init__.py')):
                package = '.'.join((parent, dir)) if parent else dir
                found.append(package)
    return found
```

This ignores the `include` and `exclude` arguments of `setuptools.find_packages()`.